# Numerical differentiation of complex valued function

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

I am trying to find the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from the following dataset,

`x                 y
===============================`

`0         0.37646 +          0i
10        0.37074 +   0.065372i
20        0.35376 +    0.12876i
30        0.32603 +    0.18823i
40        0.28839 +    0.24198i
50        0.24198 +    0.28839i
60        0.18823 +    0.32603i
70        0.12876 +    0.35376i
80       0.065372 +    0.37074i
90              0 +    0.37646i
100     -0.065372 +    0.37074i
110      -0.12876 +    0.35376i
120      -0.18823 +    0.32603i
130      -0.24198 +    0.28839i
140      -0.28839 +    0.24198i
150      -0.32603 +    0.18823i
160      -0.35376 +    0.12876i
170      -0.37074 +   0.065372i
180      -0.37646 +          0i`

where $y = y(x)$ is complex valued function.

The *exact* solution of the derivative is shown below

`x                 dy/dx (exact)
===============================`

`0        0.082825 +          0i
10       0.078016 +   0.028003i
20       0.064084 +   0.052865i
30       0.042495 +   0.071717i
40       0.015602 +    0.08225i
50      -0.013527 +   0.083005i
60      -0.041391 +   0.073629i
70      -0.064467 +    0.05504i
80      -0.079708 +   0.029423i
90      -0.085034 + 5.2068e-18i
100     -0.079708 -   0.029423i
110     -0.064467 -    0.05504i
120     -0.041391 -   0.073629i
130     -0.013527 -   0.083005i
140      0.015602 -    0.08225i
150      0.042495 -   0.071717i
160      0.064084 -   0.052865i
170      0.078016 -   0.028003i
180      0.082825 - 1.0143e-17i`

Can someone help me match the numerical derivative to the exact solution?

Comment: The numerical derivative is found the same way you would do with real numbers. There are many formulas, the most basic may be the growth rate between preceding and following point: $(u_{n+1}-u_{n-1})/(t_{n+1}-t_{n-1})$.

Comment: Hi @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, thanks! I have updated the table.

Comment: Here you may have a problem. If you plot the imaginary part of both tables, the first yields more or less a concave parabola, whereas the "derivative" looks like a period of a sine wave. However, the derivative should be monotonically decreasing. What kind of derivative is this?